# URL issue with pycurl

Tags: python, pycurl

I need to run this connamd in Python

curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/token' 
-X 'POST' 
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
-H 'Accept: application/json' 
-H 'Authorization: Basic base64_string' 
-d 'grant_type=client_credentials' 
-d 'scope=data:write data:read bucket:create bucket:delete'

I'm trying this, but I keep getting the error pycurl.error: (3, 'URL rejected: Malformed input to a URL function')

I've tried this script but I keep gettin the error pycurl.error: (3, 'URL rejected: Malformed input to a URL function'):

```
import os
import base64
import pycurl
import certifi
from io import BytesIO

sample_string = "client ID:Client Secret"
sample_string_bytes = sample_string.encode("ascii") 
  
base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(sample_string_bytes) 
base64_string = base64_bytes.decode("ascii") 
  
print(f"Encoded string: {base64_string}") 

buffer = BytesIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()

# Autodesk documentation
#curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/token' \
#   -X 'POST' \
#   -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
#   -H 'Accept: application/json' \
#   -H 'Authorization: Basic <BASE64_ENCODED_STRING_FROM_STEP_2>' \
#   -d 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
#   -d 'scope=data:write data:read bucket:create bucket:delete'

c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/token \
-X POST \
-H Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded \
-H Accept: application/json \
-H Authorization: Basic f{base64_string} \
-d grant_type=client_credentials \
-d scope=data:write data:read bucket:create bucket:delete')

c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
c.setopt(c.CAINFO, certifi.where())
c.perform()
c.close()

body = buffer.getvalue()
# Body is a byte string.
# We have to know the encoding in order to print it to a text file
# such as standard output.
print(body.decode('iso-8859-1'))
```

Comment: If this is a question about programming in Python then please provide some Python code.